# Sends an SMS message with yii2

Tags: php, sms

I started with yii2. I want to send an SMS message with yii2. Can anyone help?

I wrote this code but see no results

```
$phone = array($_POST["phone"]);
    $message = array($rand); 
    $client = new SoapClient("http://parsasms.com/webservice/v2.asmx?WSDL");
    $params = array(
        'username' => 'demo',
        'password' => 'demo',
        'senderNumbers' => array("30005006002651"),
        'recipientNumbers'=> $phone,
        'messageBodies' => $message
    )
);
$results = $client->SendSMS( $params );
```

Comment: It quite depends on http://parsasms.com/. I see your code is to send a webservice request to http://parsasms.com/webservice/v2.asmx?WSDL. It should depends on http://parsasms.com instead of yii2 or php

Comment: What's that? I tested the (parsasms.com) in php and responded

Comment: What is the response?

Comment: It works perfectly